# How to filter a wchar_t array?

Tags: c, winapi

given:

```
wchar_t filter_chars[] = L".+,?=&";
wchar_t haystack[] = L"words+punctuation&special_chars?";
```

desired result:

```
wordspunctuationspecialchars
```

how could i remove special chars from a given (unicode) string?

**i'm using win32 c (no c++)**

here is what I tried:

```
void filter(wchar_t str[]) {

    wchar_t buf[80];
    ZeroMemory(buf, 80);

    UINT i, j;

    for(i = j = 0; i < wcslen(str); i++) {
        if (!wcschr(filter_chars, str[i])) {
            wcscpy((wchar_t*)buf[j], (wchar_t*)str[i]);
        }
    }

    wcscpy(str, buf);
}
```

Comment: Wide string literals need the `L` prefix, `L"like this"`.

Comment: oops, sorry, i actually had that in my original code, but still not working.

Comment: Your loop also seems to make no sense. What's the point of `j`? And why do you always copy the entire string tail, rather than just one character?

Comment: Is there any string copy(wcscpy((wchar_t*)buf[j], (wchar_t*)str[i]); ). I think only charector wise copying is required. Also increment the valu of j too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you do it for an ordinary string:

```
/*dest must be at least strlen(src) wide*/
wchar_t *filter(wchar_t dest[], wchar_t const src[], wchar_t const filter_chars[])
{
    size_t iSrc=0, iDest=0;
    for(iSrc=0 ; src[iSrc] != L'\0' ; ++iSrc)
    {
        if(NULL == wcschr(filter_chars, src[iSrc]))
            dest[iDest++] = src[iSrc];
    }
    dest[iDest] = L'\0';
    return dest;
}
```

You can also add a version with a specified buffer size for `dest`. I don't remember how aliasing works in the standard, so you may or may not be "legally" able to call this function with `dest` equal to `src`.

Comment: You're missing the `return`.